# How to include javascript variable in google visualization referencing c# function

Tags: javascript, c#, google-visualization

There is an error when trying to include the javascript variable "selectedValue" in the c# function being called. SelectedValue has red underline error inside the GetTotalLicensesCount.

```
function drawExpireGauge() {

    var selectedValue = "30days";

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Label', 'Value'],
              ['Expiring', <%=GetTotalLicensesCount(null, null, null, selectedValue, selectedValue, null, null)%>],
              ['New', <%=GetTotalLicensesCount(null, null, null, null, null, null, selectedValue)%>],
              ['Not Used', 0]
        ]);
}
```

if "30days" is simply placed inside the GetTotalLicensesCount function instead of the variable, it works.

I did due-diligence and searched around the forum for a similar question but couldn't find any, please let me know how the question should be changed or if there is a reasonable duplicate that answers the question.

Comment: `var selectedValue = "30days";` is being executed as javascript (in the users browser) *not* in Razor (on the server before being sent to the user). Wrap it in `@{` and `}` to have it evaluated on the server. However, if `30days` is going to be taken from input from the page (for example whatever a user clicks/types in), you'll need to send a request to the server to properly evaluate it as Keith mentions

Answer (score 1):

The C# code doesn't get executed as part of the js execution.

The injected C# code you have is part of a template that will generate the js code that will eventually get executed on the client.  Therefore the C# code will not have access to "selectedValue".

so, C# code, gets run on the server, helps generate the HTTP response sent back to the client.   JS code, gets run on client once it has the response.

You have a couple of options,  Ajax back to your server to get the data, or provide all the data to js so you can write a js version of GetTotalLicensesCount.

The choice of which method depends on :-

1) how much data there is  ( small, do it in js, large, ajax)

2) if any of the data needed for the calculation is sensitive and you don't want the user to see it. (always use ajax to avoid exposing sensitive data)